# Does Windows 7 Updates really improve your system performance?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Till now I can not say I have ever seen a performance improvement or infact, any significant changes after installing Windows Updates. So my question is, how necessary is the updates for a Home user? I know Service Packs have relevant updates for certain applications propriety to Microsoft, but that is not pointed out. I would just like to know if it is really necessary and what the chances are for your system to be slowed down by the updates.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main focus of Windows updates tends to be security patches, as opposed to speed enhancements. The reason you have not seen any "significant changes" is because the updates are patching very specific circumstances, which may lead to system vulnerability. A full explanation of the reason and workings of each update is given in the Windows Update window.

In my opinion, you should download and install all updates, since there will be good reason for Microsoft to be distributing them.

Comment: Unless it is that recent update that causes chkdsk to run on every boot (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2839011).

Answer (score 3):

> Does Windows 7 Updates really improve your system performance?

No, definitely not, but nevertheless you should install ALL of them :)

Take a look at this answer please: [Which of the Windows updates are really necessary?](https://superuser.com/questions/349866/which-of-the-windows-updates-are-really-necessary)

Answer (score 1):

Most updates fix security issues, but there are some Performance updates. MS bundled 90 updates in an [Enterprise Hotfix Rollup](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sbs/archive/2013/03/20/enterprise-hotfix-rollup-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-available-now.aspx) which also helps home users because they include fixes for faster booting:

KB2510636 - An update that improves the startup performance of Windows 7 and of Windows Server 2008 R2 is available

KB2555428 - The Windows 7 startup process is slow when you create many restore points

KB2505454 - The startup process is delayed on a computer that has a large hard disk installed and is running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score -1):

I however don't recommand install all updates. Installing updates increases the size of C:\Windows\winsxs. The size easily goes to 10G. You will use up your disk soon.

The disk usage of installing Windows without Service Pack and then installing Service Pack is larger than installing Windows with SP, because Windows will backup files changed by the sp. There is a tool that can make sp permanent by removing the backup files and you cannot uninstall the sp, after which the disk usage should be same as installing Windows with sp.

If you installed AntiVirus software, you face lower security vulnerability. If you don't have AntiVirus software, like me, and rely on UAC to protect your system, don't let malware bypass UAC by exploiting security vulnerability.

I don't install antivirus software, nor install windows updates for four years and I am not infected by virus. You may become a computer expert to take the risk and win benefit.

Comment: this is foolish advice, you have no idea if you're infected with a virus or not, most specifically make themselves impossible to manually detect whilst stealing your personal details, mainly through java and flash which are notoriously insecure.

Comment: Even if you installed all updates, you have no idea if you're infected with a virus or not neither.

Comment: That's like not vaccinating yourself against measles because there's a chance you still might get measles. The sensible course of action is to get vaccinated (install patches), then see a doctor regularly (scan with anti-virus). Sitting in blissful ignorance and exclaiming its just as good as taking precautions is at best stupid and at worst dangerous, what if someone not in the know came here, saw your unwise opinions and took them as gospel, only to find that 3 months later all their personal details now belonged to Boris in Czechoslovakia.